# Evaluate $\int_S (x^2+y^2+z^2)\mathrm{d}S$.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $S=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x^2 +y^2+z^2 =1\}$. Evaluate $\int_S (x^2+y^2+z^2)\mathrm{d}S$.

**My attempt :** take $r(u,v)=(\cos v \cos u, \cos v \sin u, \sin v)$

Where $0\le u \le 2 \pi;~-\frac{\pi}{2}\le v \le \frac{\pi}{2}$

Let $~f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$. Here $~|\frac{\partial r}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial r}{\partial v}|=|\cos v|$

Then $\displaystyle \int_S(x^2+y^2+z^2)\,dS = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{2\pi} f[r(u,v)] \left|\frac{\partial r}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial r}{\partial v}\right|~du~dv$

after that im not able to proceed further

Comment: You can use divergence theorem here also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral is equal to $$ \int_S 1 = \text{Surface area}=4\pi $$

And to continue your approach you can easily see that $f(r(u,v)) =1$ thus the integral becomes

$$ \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{2\pi} |\cos(v)| dudv = 4\pi \times \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos(v) dv = 4\pi  $$